# How to set metadata

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have issue with Google Cloud Bucket. When I call my files at Google Cloud they come with the headers `private` and `max-age=0` so there will no caching options.

I use console for setting meta-data option.  I type:

```
gsutil -m setmeta -r "Cache-Control:public, max-age=3600" gs://bucket/folder*
```

but it does not work. What should I do? This is a horrible issue for me.

Comment: How do you call your file? Can you paste your base URL? can you perform a gsutil ls -L <one file in the bucket> and paste the result?

Comment: Worth noting is that I had to escape my wildcards with \ for the command to work for me from zshell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gsutil command is [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/setmeta) :

```
gsutil setmeta -h [header:value|header] ... url...
```

The following command worked for me:

```
gsutil -m setmeta -h "Cache-Control:public, max-age=3600" gs://destination/object
```

-h  Specifies a header:value to be added, or header to be removed, from each named object.

You can use wildcards with command, for example all objects:

```
gsutil -m setmeta -h "Cache-Control:public, max-age=3600"  gs://YOUR_BUCKET/**/*
```

The metadata applies only to objects and I do not think you can apply a rule to bucket to apply for future objects.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is working for each object. I did this with using this command for each object but I want to set this for whole bucket level and be sure to set this for future files. Did you know any method for this?

Comment: As explained in the answer, it is not possible to set that at bucket level. However, you can create a Cloud Function that sets the desired metadata once an object has been uploaded to your bucket. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612857/9745709) shows you how