# How to set metadata that created at certain time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to set metadata all object when created date is on 12 o'clock tonight. For now I just can set metadata for all objects that's already in a bucket with this command below :

```
gsutil -m setmeta -h "Content-Type:application/pdf" -h "Content-disposition: inline"  gs://mystorage/pdf/*.pdf
```

My plan is to set all new object by run `gsutil command` in the midnight automatically because I already make a command witch upload all file from my server to google storage every midnight. But the only problem is I don't know witch file is new.

I know that we can use [google cloud trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612857/16998479) but I just want to use `gsutil command` if it's possible

Comment: I have posted an answer. If that helped you please consider accepting and upvoting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no feature that gsutil or the GCS API provides to set metadata for objects based on timestamp.

According to [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata) `At upload time you can specify one or more metadata properties to associate with objects`.

As you mentioned `I already make a command which uploads all files from my server to google storage every midnight` you can set metadata while uploading objects. command may look like below in your case.

```
gsutil -m setmeta -h "Content-Type:application/pdf" -h "Content-disposition: inline"  cp -r images gs://bucket/images
```

Or else

you can list the objects based on [timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44017463/google-cloud-storage-how-to-get-list-of-new-files-in-bucket-folder-using-gsutil) and store the output to a file. By iterating through each line in the outfile file use your setmetadata command for the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can use [Pub/Sub notifications for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications#:%7E:text=Description-,OBJECT_FINALIZE,-Sent%20when%20a), and subscribe to the new objects event `OBJECT_FINALIZE`.

Some sample code showing this can be referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43074835/16313960)